# Proxmox Centralized Management

Tags: debian, proxmox

At my workplace, we use a lot of Proxmox servers, on various locations (some are on premise, some are hosted by hosting companies). As we are currently managing about 20 proxmox hypervisors, we would like to have a way of managing them all from one unique interface (either GUI web interface, or CLI...).
I've done some research and read that no such thing exists at the moment from official Proxmox staff ([link from Proxmox forum thread](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/centralized-management-without-a-cluster.51120/&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1567591084506000&usg=AFQjCNHaB7XFwC0kJqUsJzd1KJ6Lc3k1pA))

Have someone here experienced anything about managing various Proxmox servers with one interface ? (I'm not talking about Proxmox clusters, we don't need the shared storage, or quorum thing)

Thanks !

PS: We want to manage Proxmox itself, that is: provisioning VMs or CTs, managing users, etc

Comment: What do you want to manage? Proxmox itself? Or patches? Or configs? Or the containers/ VMs on your hypervisors?

Comment: Hi ! I should have been more precise, I will update the question. We want to manage the Proxmox themselves (patches / config can easily be managed with tools like Ansible etc, as the CTs / VMs)

Comment: Haven't done anything with Proxmox lately, but isn't this what Proxmox VE is for (at least to some degree)? Or does VE only work with Clusters?

Comment: In my understanding, Proxmox VE is the environment which provides the (para-)virtualization tools: web GUI, customised kernel, and some commands and aliases for managing guest machines, but it Seems there is no tool allowing to manage several remote Proxmox VEs in a single interface